# C# Test Box Manipulation when reading from a File

Tags: c#, textbox, file-handling

I am trying to code a simple game where my program randomly selects a word from a dictionary and stores it in a text box/or label? (Not Sure of this part). Then I have another text box where the user enters his guess.

Now I want to give the user some hint.F or example the word: 
'game' would look like '_ a m _' or 'g _ _ e'. I have no preference to how the characters are placed.

I have programmed all of the previous code including the random file handling method, all timers and counter etc. I am just stuck on this part.

The program undergoes the following code :
`var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"LOCATION");

textBox3.Text = lines[new Random().Next(lines.Length)];`

to select a random word from the file. However the whole word is being shown in textbox 3 and not parts of it like i wish. I am at a complete loss for ideas on how to proceed. I could not find anything similar on the web.

Cheers,
R

Comment: Hi, how about replacing randomly chars within the word with _ ?

Comment: For your game, you would need as many textboxes than the count of letter in the word. At beginning of your program, you may create the textboxes dynamically (the number of textboxes is equal to the length of longest word of your file) and put them in a list<TextBox>. When getting a new word, Make visible only the N first boxes (N being the length of the choosen word.

Comment: Hi @Andrei, that is what I need to do but i am not sure how to replace chars with _ in my text box ! Thanks for your thoughts on this.

Comment: Hi @Graffito, thanks for your suggestion. But if i create multiple text boxes for each character how can i compare the user's entry to all of these text boxes ?!

Comment: *Assuming that the textboxes are in "List<TextBox> tbs" do*: string word=""; for (int i=0;i<tbs.Count;i++) word+=(tbs[i].text+"  ")[0].

Comment: I supposed that, in your game, the player might complete the word by replacing unknown letters by real letters. If it is not the case, ignore my comments :(.

Comment: @Graffito, yes the player enters the full word in another text box. So he does not actually type anything in the text box where the random word is generated. Does this make sense to you ?

Comment: It's Ok and simpler to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you pick a random word from file, based on length of the word, decide on how many characters you'd want to hide and then randomly replace those many characters.

something like this-

```
    public string GetPartialWord(string word)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        char[] partialWord = word.ToCharArray();
        int numberOfCharsToHide = word.Length / 2;
        Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
        HashSet<int> maskedIndices = new HashSet<int>();
        for(int i=0;i<numberOfCharsToHide;i++)
        {
            int rIndex = randomNumberGenerator.Next(0, word.Length);
            while(!maskedIndices.Add(rIndex))
            {
                rIndex = randomNumberGenerator.Next(0, word.Length);
            }
            partialWord[rIndex] = '_';
        }
        return new string(partialWord);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts on this matter ! I will try this and see how I can alter it to fit my code. Much appreciated.

R

Comment: could you please explain The function of 
` HashSet<int> maskedIndices = new HashSet<int>();` , and
`int rIndex = randomNumberGenerator.Next(0, word.Length);` ? 
Thanks

Comment: That is to make sure we select unique indices to mask. For example when you first generate random index to mask, lets say you got 2, and then when you generate random index next time if you also get 2 then you'd want to generate another time because 2 is already masked. Hashset helps in achieving this.

Comment: Thanks for your input !

Comment: sorry for commenting on a later date on this matter. However would you be kind enough to add comments on your code above. Unfortunately, I am not finding this code simple enough for me to understand fully. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The code below will replace at least half of the characters with underscores. The code takes a word and keeps generating random numbers until it has replaced at least half of the characters with underscores.

```
public string ConvertToGuessWord(string word)
{
    var guessWord = word;
    int lastRandom = 0;
    do
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        int thisRandom = 0;
        do
        {
            thisRandom = rand.Next(0, guessWord.Length);
        } while (lastRandom == thisRandom);

        guessWord = guessWord.Replace(guessWord[thisRandom], '_');

        lastRandom = thisRandom;
    } while (guessWord.Count(x => x == '_') < (word.Length / 2));

    return guessWord;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will implement it using a randomly generated word! R

Comment: @UnknownR I am just using one word as an example. The idea is you can pass any word to it and it will do what you asked.

Comment: @UnknownR Please also note that this code guarantees that it will always make at least half of the characters underscores. If you were to send it "Comfortable", it will never return "_omfortable" etc. you get the point

Comment: Thanks @CodingYoshi for your insight !

Comment: I am still not running this successfully. No errors, however my output is the same as before.

Comment: What do you mean the output is the same as before?

Comment: The full word is showing, no missing letter to fill in. This could be because I am not displaying in textBox3 correctly.

textBox3.Text = guessWord[new Random().Next(guessWord.Length)]; 

is showing the whole word.

Comment: Once you have the random word, you will do this if you want to display the word with underscores in textBox3: `textBox3.Text = ConvertToGuessWord(randomWord);`.

Comment: Forgive my lack of knowledge, but what you seem to be doing there is converting from a 'string[]' to another 'string'.

Comment: The code worked, CodingYoshi. Thanks for your help and time.